# Ubuntu web server hosting permissions setup

Tags: wordpress, ubuntu-14.04, web-hosting

I'm running an Ubuntu web server (Ubuntu Desktop 14.04) at home and I'm using Easy Hosting Control Panel, but I keep having some permission issues with the websites. I installed Wordpress and I first had the following error:

`sorry but i can't write the wp-config.php file`

I fixed it by running the following commands on the terminal:

`sudo adduser (username) www-data`

`sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www`

`sudo chmod -R g+rwX /var/www`

But after that, I tried to install a plugin and I had the following error:

`Unable to create directory wp-content/uploads/2018/05. Is its parent directory writable by the server?`

What's the correct Ubuntu web server setup in order to avoid having permission issues in a secure way?

Answer (score 2):

[Wordpress documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Hardening_WordPress) outlines the correct permissions and tells you how to [change file permissions](https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_File_Permissions). I also have a [tutorial that covers file permissions for Wordpress](https://www.photographerstechsupport.com/tutorials/hosting-wordpress-on-aws-tutorial-part-2-setting-up-aws-for-wordpress-with-rds-nginx-hhvm-php-ssmtp/#fp).

Based on what the Wordpress site says I use this to set permissions, given the WP install is in /var/www/wp

```
chown -R tim:www-data *
find /var/www/wp -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
find /var/www/wp -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
find /var/www/wp/wp-content/uploads -type f -exec chmod 664 {} \;
find /var/www/wp/wp-content/plugins -type f -exec chmod 664 {} \;
find /var/www/wp/wp-content/themes -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
chmod 440 /var/www/wp/wp-config.php
chmod -R g+s /var/www/wp/
```